# How can I programatically add the default AJAX throbber to a form submit?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I'm trying to add the AJAX throbber in core to a form submit button, specifically the Private Message module new message page.

Here is my code:

```
function MYMODULE_form_privatemsg_new_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
'callback' => 'MYMODULE_submit_throbber_callback',
  );
}

function MYMODULE_submit_throbber_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return;
}
```

Here's what I have done so far.

First, I looked at the [Page Throbber](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_throbber) module for ideas, but this does everything in `hook_init()`, and it doesn't use the throbber included in core.  If possible, I want to avoid replicating what is already in core for a single form.

Next, I looked in the Examples module, specifically the AJAX example that includes [an AJAX submit example](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example%21ajax_example.module/function/ajax_example_submit_driven_ajax/7.x-1.x).  However, this is for adding a callback to do something else, but all I want to do is get the pager, which appears to happen automatically if you add any kind of callback.

So I added a dummy callback that just returns.  This gives me a throbber, but it breaks the submit functionality of the form.  **How do I get the throbber without breaking the form submit?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be easily done like this:

```
$form['submit']['#ajax'] = [
  'callback' => 'MYMODULE_submit_throbber_callback',
  'progress' => [
    'type' => 'throbber',
    'message' => NULL,
  ],
];
```

And then return `$form` in the callback;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a throbber on the submit button without coding, you can use the [Hide Submit](https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_submit) module.

My question is about doing it programatically, but I'm listing this as an answer for people who don't want to code.