# How to add a throbber to a submit button in a form?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

In a custom module, I have a form with a simple submit button:

```
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type'   => 'submit',
  '#value'  => $this->t('Submit'),
];
```

As the execution of the code in `submitForm` may last for a while, I'd like to add a throbber to this button.
So I updated the code to:

```
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type'  => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
  '#ajax'  => [
    'callback' => '::ajaxCallback',
    'progress' => [
      'type'    => 'throbber',
      'message' => $this->t('Be patient'),
    ],
  ],
];
```

and in my `ajaxCallback`, I have nothing as I just want the throbber to be displayed during the execution of the `submitForm`.
When I click the submit button, I get the throbber but no more validation of the form (`validateForm`) nor execution of the `submitForm`.
What am I doing wrong?

[Edit] I added

```
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="my_form_wrapper">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

and updated `$form['submit']`accordingly

```
  '#ajax'  => [
    'wrapper'  => 'my_form_wrapper',
    'callback' => '::ajaxCallback',
    'progress' => [
      'type'    => 'throbber',
      'message' => $this->t('Be patient'),
    ],
```

and now it works!

But it adds another issue:
It breaks the default location of the messages (information, warning, error).
Now they are within the wrapper :-(
[image]
I tried with different themes and I have the same result.
Any idea why and how I can fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I programatically add the default AJAX throbber to a form submit?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198956/how-can-i-programatically-add-the-default-ajax-throbber-to-a-form-submit)

Comment: The answer to that question suggests you should `return $form;` in your callback.

Comment: No, it doesn't (by the way, I had read that post). And, yes, I tried with `return $form;` with no difference.

Comment: I missed something: now I have added `$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="my_form_wrapper">';` and `$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';` it works. But it brings new issues (see how I edited my question).

Comment: Please ask a new question then.

Comment: Might be a CSS issue. Test with the default, Bartik, theme.

Comment: AS I said in my edited question, I tried with others themes. With same results. I will follow suggestion from @leymannx and ask a new question.